# Who owns domain purchased via GoogleApps?

Tags: google-app-engine

My original plan was to use google appengine for an application.  For this I purchased a domain via GoogleApps at Godaddy.  Since Google Appengine fails to impress me, I would love to move my website to another server.  But who is the owner of the domain now? GoogleApp "purchased" the domain for me - how can I regain control over the domain I paid for?

Answer (score 3):

You paid $10 for the domain didn't you?  That makes the domain yours.  Google Apps is merely the portal through which you manage it.  If you login to GoDaddy, through Google Apps, you can configure the domain to point to another webserver by changing your A record and MX records.

Of course, why would you want to do that?  What makes App Engine so unimpressive in your eyes?  Do you like having to spend 20 hours managing your Tomcat upgrades like this guy [Nightmare: Upgrading Tomcat 5.5 to 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577849/nightmare-upgrading-tomcat-5-5-to-6-0) or would you prefer to let Google handle those mundane details so you can concentrate on what you do best, building software!

Platform as a Service is, after all, the future.  By the time you figure out how to get your app to production, Google App Engine will most likely no longer be in BETA and could be the new standard.

I encourage you to build your application with the future in mind, as in the world of web development, what's considered mainstream today will be obsolete tomorrow, and what's in beta/unstable today will take it's place.  Technology moves incredibly fast; don't be left behind.

Comment: My mistake.  For some reason I couldn't find the login info for godaddy, now I found it, thanks for the pointer.  I was kind of worried that Google somehow owned the domain and that I could only manage it via my Google account.  As for the platform as service, I'm not quite sure yet if I need more control than appengine provides, since I have a couple special requirements (server push via websockets).  I guess I'll check out the new channel API and see how that goes.

Comment: Yes, I'd recommend the Channel API.  By the time your app is in production, Google may very well have included a setting to use Websockets through the Channel API.  Check out this demo here:  http://blog.conversionsupport.com/2010/12/channelapi-comet-chat-demo-on-google.html.  Also, since when has Google ever tried to lock us in ;)

Comment: LOL.  I like app engine but i think your argument for it is a bit pushier than I'm comfortable with - not everyone spends 20 hours upgrading tomcat, and for every one who does, there is probably someone out there who struggled with JDO on appengine for 20 hours trying to figure out why their objects aren't consistently getting updated in the datastore, only to find out it is a known bug, and they actually were doing everything right themselves :(  Not that I would know anything about that painful experience...

Comment: I'm using Python, so all those Tomcat struggles do not apply ;)